# Sending XML to a JS chart/map library

Tags: xml, database, charts

I need to generate a chart or map map (tiles with points, lines, polygons) using data from a database but I am not a javascript programmer. I find debugging browser issues and manipulating DOM elements very time consuming.

Some chart libraries I've used before ("Anychart" springs to mind) have a feature where all attributes about the chart can be sent in a block of XML: the chart display attributes, the series details, legend/axes/labels, and finally a  block containing all of the data with series name tags. As a database programmer, it would be faster for me to generate the XML block inside the database using a procedural language (yes, concatenating up a large XML string). When the chart is created, the XML is returned to the visualisation library in the browser, which should accept the XML and render the map (or chart) with minimal coding in Javascript/ajax - esepcially no handling of individual data rows.

Which javascript visualisation library (for maps or charts, or both) can be used to render a chart with both the data and chart attributes inside a single XML block?

Comment: *"generate the XML block inside the database using a procedural language"* - I hope you are not talking about "concatenating strings that contain angle brackets" here.

Comment: Besides, questions for library recommendations are off-topic here, as they tend to incite opinionated answers and go out of date really quickly. That said, " most (or all) of the chart/map attributes as a single XML block" is pretty vague.